# How do I use the Alexa Voice Service device SDK in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, alexa-voice-service, alexa-skills-kit

I have successfully built the AVS Device SDK on Android with the help of the reference guide to building Device SDK on Android that the Amazon team sent me. However, as a novice Android developer, I don't know where to go from here to actually use the SDK in an Android app. For example, I'd like to press a button in my app to activate Alexa and speak to her/it. How would I proceed after successfully building SDK on Android? I have pushed the local build with all the compiled libraries to the adb shell and have ran most tests successfully.

I know I'm most likely going to have to user NDK and JNI, but yeah, some guidance would be great.

Also, would it be possible to run your sample app on Android? I am aware of the previous Android sample app, but I'd like to try running this new C++ SDK sample app on Android too.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to build it on your own. There is no official support to iOS/Android in avs-device-sdk and Alexa assets are not public (e.g. Alexa logo for the button).

In order to make it work, you should integrate LoginWithAmazon SDK and once you have a valid token you should be able to start using AVS.

I hope an official iOS/Android AVS SDK will come anytime soon.